How to convert ids to JUUID format from mongo shell script output
With MongoDB id stored in Java LUUID (legacy representation), when a script is run to retrieve these ids, the output shows them in binary format:
var myStringArray = ["string1",
    "string2"];

for (var i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {

    let outputs = db.getCollection("MyCollection").aggregate(
        {
            '$match': {
                "field1": myStringArray[i]
            }
        }

        , { $project: { _id: 1, "field1": 1 } }
    ).map(function (el) { return EJSON.stringify(el) });

    console.log(outputs);
} 

Output:
[
  '{"_id":{"$binary":{"base64":"Z0raDiKJKdjkWnqi5TvWjQ==","subType":"03"}},"field1":"string1"}'
]
[
  '{"_id":{"$binary":{"base64":"a0xH8uquuKwwbsRc4LggvA==","subType":"03"}},"field1":"string2"}'
]

Would prefer to see the "_id" shown similar to "_id": JUUID("ACB8AEEA-D247-4C6B-BC20-B8E05C146F30").
NOTE: I am not asking how to store in subtype 4 (standard) UUID format. The MongoDB driver is set to UuidRepresentation.JAVA_LEGACY and this will not change.

1. Check Spring Data Entity UUID is stored as legacy UUID in MongoDB 2. Also see this answer on the MongoDB Forums: How to store a UUID with binary subtype 0x04 using the MongoDB Java Driver - the linked answer refers to "subType": "03"

Thanks for your comments. I am not asking how to store in a different format. I am asking how to retrieve the output differently.

You can't just change the representation when you are querying the data in a language that doesn't have LUUIDs. You'll either need to write a JS function or convert it in an aggregation pipeline. And even then, it won't display as JUUID("ACB8AEEA-D247-4C6B-BC20-B8E05C146F30") because that 'JUUID(...)' is a keyword. You could try to get it to be: "JUUID("ACB8AEEA-D247-4C6B-BC20-B8E05C146F30")" fully as a string by doing the conversion along with some string concatenation.

I'd be satisfied to get it like ACB8AEEAD2474C6BBC20B8E05C146F30, but as it is I can't even get it to that point. I also can get it to print like Binary(Buffer.from("104e0635d23ee22d593e5fb157b5659f", "hex"), 3), but I'm not sure how to convert that to LUUID.

With the latest MongoDB v8.0 release, you have a new option of $toUUID
sample data:
db.uuid.insertOne({
    "_id":Binary.createFromBase64('Z0raDiKJKdjkWnqi5TvWjQ==', 3),
    "field1":"string1"
});

example syntax of $toUUID:
db.uuid.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      uuid: {
        $toUUID: "$_id"
      }
    }
  }
])

sample output:
{
  _id: Binary.createFromBase64('Z0raDiKJKdjkWnqi5TvWjQ==', 3),
  field1: 'string1',
  uuid: UUID('674ada0e-2289-29d8-e45a-7aa2e53bd68d')
}


Prior to MongoDB v8.0, you may use $function to perform UUID conversion with javascript's hex function. After the conversion, you can use $concat and $substrCP to reform your UUID string.
Please be reminded:

$function may decrease performance. From official doc,


Executing JavaScript inside an aggregation expression may decrease performance. Only use the $function operator if the provided pipeline operators cannot fulfill your application's needs.


$function is deprecated in future versions of MongoDB. From official doc,


Starting in MongoDB 8.0, server-side JavaScript functions ($accumulator, $function, $where) are deprecated. MongoDB logs a warning when you run these functions.

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "uuid": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(id) {return id.hex()}",
          "args": [
            "$_id"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "uuid": {
        "$concat": [
          {
            "$substrCP": [
              "$uuid",
              0,
              8
            ]
          },
          "-",
          {
            "$substrCP": [
              "$uuid",
              8,
              4
            ]
          },
          "-",
          {
            "$substrCP": [
              "$uuid",
              12,
              4
            ]
          },
          "-",
          {
            "$substrCP": [
              "$uuid",
              16,
              4
            ]
          },
          "-",
          {
            "$substrCP": [
              "$uuid",
              20,
              12
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Good to know. Alas, I'm still using ver 5.0.

@awgtek updated another solution with $function that might be viable before MongoDB v8.0

Oddly, the $toUUID page doesn't mention that it's new in version 8.0. But it is in the 8.0 release notes. I wanted to answer with $convert but the format param was throwing an error so I figured it was a bug in Mongo 6 & 7. Now I see that it's new in 8.0. Will add an answer for that once I have a local 8.0 instance.

The closest to getting a hex-representation is to use .toString('hex', 3).
db.collection.insertOne({_id: BinData(3, "Z0raDiKJKdjkWnqi5TvWjQ==") ,"field1":"string1"})
var doc = db.collection.findOne({})
doc._id.toString('hex')  // 674ada0e228929d8e45a7aa2e53bd68d

// to verify that 
Binary.createFromHexString(doc._id.toString('hex', 3), 3)
// returns Binary.createFromBase64('Z0raDiKJKdjkWnqi5TvWjQ==', 3)

Binary.createFromHexString("674ada0e228929d8e45a7aa2e53bd68d", 3)
// returns Binary.createFromBase64('Z0raDiKJKdjkWnqi5TvWjQ==', 3)

For your data and code, use this:
db.collection.insertMany([
  { "_id": BinData(3, "Z0raDiKJKdjkWnqi5TvWjQ=="), "field1": "string1" },
  { "_id": BinData(3, "a0xH8uquuKwwbsRc4LggvA=="), "field1": "string2" },
]);

var myStringArray = ["string1", "string2"];

for (var i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {
    let output = db.getCollection("collection").aggregate(
        { $match: { "field1": myStringArray[i] } },
        { $project: { _id: 1, "field1": 1 }
    }).map(function (el) {
        el._id = el._id.toString('hex', 3)  // NOTE this line
        return el
    });
    console.log(output);
}

Output is:
{
  _id: '674ada0e228929d8e45a7aa2e53bd68d',
  field1: 'string1'
}
{
  _id: '6b4c47f2eaaeb8ac306ec45ce0b820bc',
  field1: 'string2'
}


toString('hex',3) is good to know. Like I said, I could get it already in in hex, but was stumped on how to get it displayed in how you see it in "Legacy Mongo Shell Format" (like in Studio 3T document viewer). What I found that is if I used the new JUUID function here (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/2.6.1/uuidhelpers.js) I can then take output base64 and reconvert it to hex and I get the JUUID as shown in robomongo / Studio3T. What I don't know is why this works. I may put all this in the question or another answer.

Yeah, post that as an alternative answer, especially since you're doing it in Mongo shell / JS / JS application. And you'd just need to change the el._id =  line to el._id = JUUID(el._id) or el._id = el._id.toJUUID() if you can use the prototype func.

I came up with the following solution which works for my purposes. It borrows from this old version of some helper functions I came across. Big shout out to @aneroid for assistance with the methods.
var myStringArray = ["string1",
    "string2"];

for (var i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {

    let outputs = db.getCollection("MyCollection").aggregate(
        {
            '$match': {
                "field1": myStringArray[i]
            }
        }

        , { $project: { _id: 1, "field1": 1 } }
    ).map(function (el) {
        el._id = toJUUID(JUUID(el._id.toString('hex', 3)))
        return EJSON.stringify(el);
    });

    console.log(outputs);

} 

function JUUID(uuid) {
    var hex = uuid.replace(/[{}-]/g, ""); // remove extra characters
    var msb = hex.substr(0, 16);
    var lsb = hex.substr(16, 16);
    msb = msb.substr(14, 2) + msb.substr(12, 2) + msb.substr(10, 2) + msb.substr(8, 2) + msb.substr(6, 2) + msb.substr(4, 2) + msb.substr(2, 2) + msb.substr(0, 2);
    lsb = lsb.substr(14, 2) + lsb.substr(12, 2) + lsb.substr(10, 2) + lsb.substr(8, 2) + lsb.substr(6, 2) + lsb.substr(4, 2) + lsb.substr(2, 2) + lsb.substr(0, 2);
    hex = msb + lsb;
        var lsb = hex.substr(16, 16);
    msb = msb.substr(14, 2) + msb.substr(12, 2) + msb.substr(10, 2) + msb.substr(8, 2) + msb.substr(6, 2) + msb.substr(4, 2) + msb.substr(2, 2) + msb.substr(0, 2);
    lsb = lsb.substr(14, 2) + lsb.substr(12, 2) + lsb.substr(10, 2) + lsb.substr(8, 2) + lsb.substr(6, 2) + lsb.substr(4, 2) + lsb.substr(2, 2) + lsb.substr(0, 2);
    hex = msb + lsb;
    
    var base64 = HexToBase64(hex);
    return new BinData(3, base64);
}
function toJUUID(binData) {
    var hex = binData.toString('hex');
    var msb = hex.substr(0, 16);
    var lsb = hex.substr(16, 16);
    msb = msb.substr(14, 2) + msb.substr(12, 2) + msb.substr(10, 2) + msb.substr(8, 2) + msb.substr(6, 2) + msb.substr(4, 2) + msb.substr(2, 2) + msb.substr(0, 2);
    lsb = lsb.substr(14, 2) + lsb.substr(12, 2) + lsb.substr(10, 2) + lsb.substr(8, 2) + lsb.substr(6, 2) + lsb.substr(4, 2) + lsb.substr(2, 2) + lsb.substr(0, 2);
    hex = msb + lsb;
    return hex.substr(0, 8) + '-' + hex.substr(8, 4) + '-' + hex.substr(12, 4) + '-' + hex.substr(16, 4) + '-' + hex.substr(20, 12);
}

Output:
[
  '{"_id":"d8098922-0eda-4a67-8dd6-3be5a27a5ae4","field1":"string1"}'
]
[
  '{"_id":"acb8aeea-f247-4c6b-bc20-b8e05c146f30","field1":"string2"}'
]


The problem with type 3 (legacy) UUIDs is the ordering of the bytes was left up to the language generating the data.
This means that java, c#, python, node, etc. could all generate a slightly different binary representation for the same UUID.
This in turn means that when queried with the shell, there is no way to be certain what the original UUID was, so rather than display a potentially incorrect UUID, the shell code opts to display the binary encoding as it was stored alongside the data.
For example, one of the UUIDs you showed was
{"$binary":{"base64":"Z0raDiKJKdjkWnqi5TvWjQ==","subType":"03"}}

Directly decoding that base64 string gives
674ada0e-2289-29d8-e45a-7aa2e53bd68d

That is almost certainly not the UUID you intended to store.
With the knowledge that this UUID was generated by Java, and therefore likely stored using the Java driver, the actual UUID was probably
d8298922-0eda-4a67-8dd6-3be5a27a5ae4

But extracting that UUID required the additional knowledge of what generated it in the first place, which is not stored.
If the UUID had been generated by Python, it would need to be extracted differently.
This is why type 4 UUIDs were introduced.  Type 4 defines the ordering for the bytes within the binary representation, so no matter which language or driver generated the value, any other driver can properly return the original UUID.
If you want to display the Type 3 UUID values differently using the mongosh shell, you will need to define a custom function.
